# how to include \ in the string as pattern for regex python

Tags: python, regex, string

Using the regex in python, I want to compile a string that gets the pattern "\1" up to "\9".
I've tried

```
regex= re.compile("\\(\d)")  #sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
regex= re.compile("\\\(\d)") #gets \\4 but not \4
```

but to no avail..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more: `re.compile("\\\\(\\d)")`. Or, a better option, a raw string: `re.compile(r"\\(\d)")`.

The reason is the fact that backslash has meaning in both a string and in a regexp. For example, in regexp, `\d` is "a digit"; so you can't just use `\` for a backslash, and backslash is thus `\\`. But in a normal string, `\"` is a quote, so a backslash needs to be `\\`. When you combine the two, the string `"\\\\(\\d)"` actually contains `\\(\d)`, which is a regexp that matches `\` and a digit.

Raw strings avoid the problem up to a point by giving backslashes a different and much more restricted semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (which does not process escape sequences):

```
regex= re.compile(r"\\(\d)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use raw string:

```
regex= re.compile(r"\\(\d)")
```